# Alternate display of 2 strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java program where the following is what I wanted to achieve:

```
first input: ABC

second input: xyz

output: AxByCz
```

and my Java program is as follows:

```
    import java.io.*;

    class DisplayStringAlternately 
    {
        public static void main(String[] arguments)
        {
            String firstC[], secondC[];

            firstC = new String[] {"A","B","C"};
            secondC = new String[] {"x","y","z"};

            displayStringAlternately(firstC, secondC);        
        }

        public static void displayStringAlternately (String[] firstString, String[] secondString)
        {
           int combinedLengthOfStrings = firstString.length + secondString.length;

           for(int counter = 1, i = 0; i < combinedLengthOfStrings; counter++, i++)
           {
               if(counter % 2 == 0)
               {
                   System.out.print(secondString[i]);
               }
               else 
               {
                   System.out.print(firstString[i]);
               }
           }
        }        
    }
```

however I encounter the following runtime error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    AyC at DisplayStringAlternately.displayStringAlternately(DisplayStringAlternately.java:23)
        at DisplayStringAlternately.main(DisplayStringAlternately.java:12)
    Java Result: 1
```

What mistake is in my Java program?

Comment: Both array length is same ?

Comment: Neither of your arrays have an index of 3. Both have indexes of 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: You are incrementing i once per iteration of the for-loop. It seems like you only want to increment it every two iterations.

Comment: yes @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ. They are both same in lenght

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682053/how-to-mix-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: @vishnu Added my answer. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both arrays have same length `for` loop should continue while `i < anyArray.length`.

Also you don't need any `counter` to determine from which array you should print first. Just hardcode that first element will be printed from `firstString` and next one from `secondString`.

So your `displayStringAlternately` method can look like

```
public static void displayStringAlternately(String[] firstString,
        String[] secondString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(firstString[i]);
        System.out.print(secondString[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Anyway your code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because each time you decide from which array print element you are incrementing `i`, so effectively you are jumping through arrays this way

```
 i=0     i=2
{"A","B","C"};

{"x","y","z"};    
     i=1     i=3 
             ^^^-here is the problem
```

so as you see your code tries to access element from second array which is not inside of it (it is out of its bounds).

Comment: thank you. Though there are other acceptable answers, yours has more in depth explanation. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As you commented, If both arrays length is same, you can simply do

```
 firstC = new String[] {"A","B","C"};
 secondC = new String[] {"x","y","z"};
```

Then

```
          for(int i = 0; i < firstC.length; i++)  {
                   System.out.print(firstC[i]);
                   System.out.print(secondC[i]);
           }
```

Comment: This is the proper solution if the arrays are guaranteed to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Using the combined length of the Strings is wrong, since, for example, `secondString[i]` would cause an exception when i >= secondString.length.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below working code with high performance

```
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    String firstC[], secondC[];

    firstC = new String[] {"A","B","C"};
    secondC = new String[] {"x","y","z"};
    StringBuilder  builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < firstC.length; i++) {
        builder.append(firstC[i]);
        builder.append(secondC[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class concad {

```
public void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "RAMESH";
    String s2 = "SURESH";

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        for (j = i; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                System.out.print(s2.charAt(j));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the purpose of the second `for` loop? It has only one iteration ... _always_. And the value of `j` is _always_ the same as in `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken two strings as mentioned.Then pass one counter variable in inner for-loop with second string,Then for every even position pass with code "counter%2".Check this out if any concern then comment below.

```
public class AlternatePosition {

public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    String abc = "abcd";
    String def = "efgh";
    displayStringAlternately(abc, def);
}

public static void displayStringAlternately(String firstString, String secondString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < firstString.length(); i++) {
        for (int counter = 1, j = 0; j < secondString.length(); counter++, j++) {
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(secondString.charAt(i));
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print(firstString.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you could had some description in your answer. It would be more useful for future readers