# Merge 3 list items

Tags: java

I have 3 list in Java and how do I merge them?

```
list1 = [10,20,30]
list2 = [40,50,60]
list3 = [70]
```

Output

res = [10,40,70,20,50,30,60]

I'm familiar with writing a achieving the result but would like to know if there
is any libraries that I can use it.

Comment: "I'm familiar with...", can you give us an example of what you normally do?

Answer (score 1):

```
res = ArrayUtils.addAll(list1, list2);
res = ArrayUtils.addall(res,list3);
```

Also, see many more options on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

from [How to mix two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682053/how-to-mix-two-arrays-in-java)

```
int[] merge(int[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    for (int[] a: arrays) {
        length += a.length;
    }
    int result[] = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < length; ++i) {
        for (int[] a: arrays) {
            if (i < a.length) {
                result[j++] = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

then simply

```
merge(list1, list2, list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal Java 7 libraries:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
result.addAll(list1); result.addAll(list2); result.addAll(list3);`
```

or  shorter:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(result, list1, list2, list3);
```

I guess there is also a Java 8 stream solution.